# PHP 8.1 Makefile

Tags: php, makefile

Where is the Makefile file?

I am trying to compile PHP 8.1 on my machine (Ubuntu 20.04). I have downloaded it from https://www.php.net/downloads I have run `./buildconf` and `./configure`, but when I run `./make` it says it can't find the file `Makefile`. I only see two similar files: `Makefile.fragments` and `Makefile.objects`

```
~/projects/php-8.1.0 » ls -ld M*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ricardo ricardo  2791 dic  6 13:59 Makefile.fragments
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ricardo ricardo 17487 dic  6 13:59 Makefile.objects
```

Comment: Are you sure `./configure` succeeded?  No error messages?

Comment: I've already figured out what was wrong: the libxml2-dev package was missing. Thanks @G.M.